# Can’t shrink C: drive beyond 941MB

Tags: windows, partitioning

I'm using a Surface Pro 3 running Windows 10 and I have 14GB Free on my `C:\` drive. But whenever I shrink it it only says I have 941MB avalible to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have a file that cannot be relocated stopping you. You cannot shrink the drive if an unmovable system file, such as the page file, is towards the end of the drive.

> When you shrink a partition, certain files (for example, the paging file or the shadow copy storage area) cannot be automatically relocated and you cannot decrease the allocated space beyond the point where the unmovable files are located.
>
> ...
>
> In some cases, you can relocate the file temporarily. For example, if the unmovable file is the paging file, you can use Control Panel to move it to another disk, shrink the volume, and then move the page file back to the disk.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731894.aspx

Comment: Yes, but is there any way around this?